# Start-Process passing a hashtable in the ArgumentList

Tags: powershell, arguments, parameter-passing, start-process

Consider the following situation:

**Content `MyScript.ps1`:**

```
Param (
    [String]$CountryCode,
    [String]$FilesPath,
    [String]$KeepassDatabase,
    [String]$KeepassKeyFile,
    [String]$EventLog = 'HCScripts',
    [String]$EventSource,
    [HashTable]$CitrixFarm = @{'Server1' = '6.5'}
)

$CountryCode
$FilesPath
$KeepassDatabase
$KeepassKeyFile
$EventLog
$EventSource
$CitrixFarm
```

**Content of the `Caller.ps1`:**

```
Param (
    $FilesPath = ".\MyScript.ps1",
    $EvenntLog = 'Test',
    $CountryCode = 'BNL',
    $KeepasDatabase,
    $KeepasKeyFile
)

$Arguments = @()
$Arguments += "-EventSource ""$AppName"""
$Arguments += "-EventLog ""$EventLog"""
$Arguments += "-FilesPath ""$((Get-Item $FilesPath).FullName)"""
$Arguments += "-CountryCode ""$CountryCode"""
$Arguments += "-KeepassDatabase ""$((Get-Item $KeepasDatabase).FullName)"""
$Arguments += "-KeepassKeyFile ""$((Get-Item $KeepasKeyFile).FullName)"""
$Arguments += "-CitrixFarm $CitrixFarm"

$StartParams = @{
    Credential   = $Credentials
    ArgumentList = "-File ""$ScriptPath"" -verb runas" + $Arguments
    WindowStyle  = 'Hidden'
}
Start-Process powershell @StartParams
```

We can't seem to find a way to pass in the `[HashTable]` for the argument `$CitrixFarm`. How is it possible to add that argument. or pass it on to the script called by `Start-Process` with elevated permissions and in a new PowerShell session?

When omitting the parameter `$CitrixFarm` all is working fine. So the problem really is with passing the `HashTable`.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with `-verb runas`?

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 `-Verb runas` requests elevation.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart I understand that it does, but does he need it? Why is he trying to start a different powershell process if he doesn't need to?

Comment: You need to convert the hashtable back to its PowerShell object notation [using a function](https://www.sapien.com/blog/2014/10/21/a-better-tostring-method-for-hash-tables/).

Comment: What is the `$CitrixFarm` parameter's argument supposed to look like on the command line?

Comment: @Bill_Stewart The `$CitrixFarm` parameter is a simple hashtable like `-CitrixFarm @{'ServerName1' = 'XenApp 7.15'}`

Comment: @DanWilson your answer is the only answer that works. Apparently the `ArgumentList` of `Start-Process` can only accept `[String]` objects. If you put your answer, I'll mark it as solved. Thank you :)

Comment: I umderstand that. But you want to convert it to `[String]`. What is that supposed to look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass the hashtable in PowerShell object notation, just as you would if running the script from a PowerShell window.

How you construct the string is up to you.

You could

- use a string template
- use a quick-and-dirty call `"@$((ConvertTo-Json $CitrixFarm -Compress) -replace ':','=')"`
- [use a function](https://www.sapien.com/blog/2014/10/21/a-better-tostring-method-for-hash-tables/) to convert the hashtable object.

Below is effectively what you are trying to achieve.

```
$Arguments = @()
...
$Arguments += "-CitrixFarm @{'Server1' = '6.5'}"

$StartParams = @{
    Credential   = $Credentials
    ArgumentList = "-File ""$ScriptPath"" -verb runas" + $Arguments
    WindowStyle  = 'Hidden'
}
Start-Process powershell @StartParams
```

Source: [A Better ToString() Method for Hash Tables](https://www.sapien.com/blog/2014/10/21/a-better-tostring-method-for-hash-tables/)