# refactoring powershell functions that use switches

Tags: powershell

I'm in the process of refactoring some powershell code, I have a function that has multiple switch parameters. I want to take a certain amount of code out of this function and place it into another which I then call from the original function. The problem is this, how do I invoke the child function without having to check what switch parameters are present in the parent and then account for all permutations of calls to the child function.

This is the param list for my 'Parent' function, most of the switch params will be passed into the child function:

```
param(
      [parameter(mandatory=$true)]  [string]                                    $RefreshDatabase          
     ,[parameter(mandatory=$true)]  [string]                                    $RefreshSource 
     ,[parameter(mandatory=$true)]  [string[]]                                  $DestSqlInstances   
     ,[parameter(mandatory=$true)]  [string]                                    $PfaEndpoint       
     ,[parameter(mandatory=$true)]  [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential] $PfaCredentials
     ,[parameter(mandatory=$false)] [switch]                                    $PromptForSnapshot
     ,[parameter(mandatory=$false)] [switch]                                    $RefreshFromSnapshot
     ,[parameter(mandatory=$false)] [switch]                                    $NoPsRemoting
     ,[parameter(mandatory=$false)] [switch]                                    $ApplyDataMasks
     ,[parameter(mandatory=$false)] [switch]                                    $ForceDestDbOffline 
     ,[parameter(mandatory=$false)] [string]                                    $StaticDataMaskFile
)
```

Comment: It would help if you show us some of the code. Usually with switch parameters you can send them through to the next function using `-SwitchParam:$SwitchParam`

Comment: Either what @Theo says or just passing bound parameters along. If you want more concise advice, please show some examples

Comment: I've added the param list for the parent function , see above.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the end, in the child function that I was passing the switch parameters to, I specified the corresponding arguments as having boolean data types, and I passed the switch parameters in as SwitchParam1.IsPresent, SwitchParam2.IsPresent . . . etc . I don't know if this is the most elegant solution, but it worked.

Something like this:

```
ParentFunc {
    param(
           [parameter(mandatory=$false)] [switch] $ParentParam1                              
          ,[parameter(mandatory=$false)] [switch] $ParentParam2                                   
    )
.
.
.

ChildFunc {
    param(
           [parameter(mandatory=$false)] [bool] $ChildParam1                                  
          ,[parameter(mandatory=$false)] [bool] $ChildParam2                                
    )
.
.
.
```

Then you call ChildFunc as follows:

```
ChildFunc $ParentParam1.IsPresent, $ParentParam2.IsPresent
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either send these switch parameters through using:

```
MyNewFunction -PromptForSnapshot:$PromptForSnapshot -RefreshFromSnapshot:$RefreshFromSnapshot -NoPsRemoting:$NoPsRemoting -ApplyDataMasks:$ApplyDataMasks -ForceDestDbOffline:$ForceDestDbOffline
```

or for better readability use splatting:

```
$params = @{
    'PromptForSnapshot'   = $PromptForSnapshot
    'RefreshFromSnapshot' = $RefreshFromSnapshot
    'NoPsRemoting'        = $NoPsRemoting
    'ApplyDataMasks'      = $ApplyDataMasks
    'ForceDestDbOffline'  = $ForceDestDbOffline 
}

MyNewFunction @params
```

If your secondary function uses different parameter names, you need to account for that of course.

Then you could have a look at the [$PSBoundParameters](https://ss64.com/ps/psboundparameters.html) automatic variable.

Comment: And I presume this will take into account whether the switch parameters have been specified or not in the call to the parent function ?

Comment: @ChrisAdkin Yes, switch parameters that have not been specified in the call to the parent function will simply pass through the default values which will be interpreted as $true of $false

Comment: @ChrisAdkin Actually, a [switch] parameter doesn't take a value like regular parameters. They are objects that have a property called `IsPresent`. If you pass a switch not specified in the parent function like in the code above, the secondary function will have the value for the `IsPresent` property on that parameter `False` as if it was not specified.

Comment: For the second approach which you recommend for improved readability, can I somehow use this in the argument list passed to Start-Job.

Comment: @ChrisAdkin I've never tried that, but I don't think that is possible. You can set up a parameter to receive a Hashtable I guess, but then the function receiving that needs to parse it, unlike what happens with parameters. Something like I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50510087/9898643) perhaps.